# angularjs - trim() function is not working

Tags: angularjs, input, trim

This is my js code that deletes multiple spaces in string and trim string:

```
$scope.fixInput = function (input){
    input = input.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
    return input;
};
```

And i have input field in html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userName" ng-change="userName=fixInput(userName)"/>
```

And there is a strange behaviour. When i type for example

```
"    a    a       a   "
```

the result will be fine

> "a a a"

but when i type

```
"       aaa        "
```

when it has to just to trim string the result is not changing, it's the same.

Comment: Changing model on model change, can't this be dangerous (e.g. infinitely looping)?

Comment: I have just use this code snippet at browser console `var v= "       aaa        ";
v.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();` and found the output as `aaa`. So is it fine or you are expecting something else?

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar I also saw that and it confuses me. But the value in input is not changing.

Comment: I just tried it in angular context and found an error, the input.replace is not a function

Comment: sorry, my bad. It gives me expected result`var app = angular.module("test",[])
.controller("TestController", function($http,$scope){
 var vm = this;
 vm.my = true;
 $scope.fixInput = function (input){
 console.log(input);
    input = input.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
    return input;
};
});
`

Answer (score 1):

Angular automatically trims `input[text]`. If you want to do it manually, you have to disable it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userName" ng-trim="false" ng-change="userName=fixInput(userName)" />
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D:

> If set to false AngularJS will not automatically trim the input. This
>   parameter is ignored for input[type=password] controls, which will
>   never trim the input.
>
> (default: true)

Comment: i tried with that and i removed trim function and now i'm getting what i want, i just have one space at the begining and at the end that i have to trim